# Create directory where specific files exist in ruby

Tags: ruby

Using the following two lines I create the file "tmp.txt" in each directory where file_name exist. Than I open the file and write into it an array which I created before:

```
tmp_file = File.expand_path(File.dirname(file_name)) + "/temp.txt"
File.open(tmp_file, 'w') {|f| f.write array.join("\n")}
```

How can I create now also a empty directory into the same directories where tmp.txt is created?

I tried something like this:

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(file_name)) + FileUtils.mkdir("/NewDirectory")
```

Comment: The first line doesn't create a new file, it only returns a path.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. I do not understand why you thought that a path ending with `"temp.txt"` would be related to creating a file named `"tmp.txt"`.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm creating the tmp.txt and than write into it some strings (which comes from an array). Have edited the question now hopefully for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Create directory path and pass it to [`FileUtils.mkdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir).

BTW, Instead of concatenate using `+`, use [`File::join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-join) instead:

```
dirpath = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(file_name), 'NewDirectory'))
FileUtils.mkdir(dirpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a correct dirname to mkdir:

```
FileUtils.mkdir(File.expand_path(File.dirname(file_name)) + "/NewDirectory")
```